# How can I render more than one field value in the controller?

Tags: page-controller

in my case i have a controller that it send for me the title , to the view , but i want to send the tittle and the body of the article both , i have tried to send them from the controller but it doesn't work for me

how can i send them both from the controller (title and body) ?

> here is tmy controller

```
 public function myPage() {
    $data = \Drupal::service('myservice.ran');
    $dataService = $data->getArticles();
    return $this->renderMyPage($dataService);
  }
  function renderMyPage($articleObjects) {
    $articles = [];
    foreach ($articleObjects as $article) {
      $articles[] = [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#html_tag' => 'h2',
        '#value' => [$article->title->value,$article->body->value],
        '#cache' => [
          'tags' => $article->getCacheTags(),
        ],
      ];
    }
    return $articles;
  }
```

Comment: You want both the title and the body inside the h2 tag? `#value` only takes strings. See [class HtmlTag](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21HtmlTag.php/class/HtmlTag). So you either concat both values or you build a different render array. Probably best would be you use `hook_theme` to add your own template.

Comment: @leymannx. instead of #value you could put render children (array keys not starting with `#`) in html_tag and so create a nested render array, for example a `#plain_text` for the title and `'#type' => 'processed_text'` for the body to output the field values safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is the this solution, create a custom template, for your page, in controller pass the data to the twig template.

```
public function myPage() {

    $data = \Drupal::service('myservice.ran');
    $dataService = $data->getArticles();
    $articles = [];
    foreach ($dataService as $article) {
      $articles[] = [
        'title' => $article->title->value,
        'body' => $article->body->value,
      ];
    }
    $build = [
      '#theme' => 'my_template',
      '#data' => [
        'articles' => $articles,
        'whatelse' => "what esle I want"
      ],
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
    ];
    $output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($output);
    return $response;
  }
```

then all the data will be available on `data` in your custom twig template. ( you can change its name to whatever you want).

just be sure you clear the cache when you create your custom template.

[A helper article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example)

Comment: Why not just `return $build`, instead of rendering it in the controller and returning the rendered output?